# Splunk search the key in json

Tags: splunk

Could anyone help me with the below Splunk query?

I want to get the `count` of records by `message.type`. The `message.type` can take value either 'typeA' or 'typeB'.

I tried the below query but it lists and doesn't give the `count` in the result. That is, separate `count` for typeA and typeB.

The messages are below.

```
message: name=app1,version=1, type=typeA,task=queryapp
message: name=app2,version=1, type=typeB,task=testapp
message: name=app1,version=1, type=typeB,task=issuefix
```

```
index=myapp message="name=app1" 
| stats count by message.type
```

Comment: What are you getting now that makes you think your SPL is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would modify the logs so that type is its own json field.

However, if you are stuck with with

`{"message" : "name=app1,version=1, type=typeA,task=queryapp"}`

Then I suggest the following solution:

```
index=myapp message=*
| rex field=message "type=(?<myType>[a-zA-Z]+)"
| stats count by myType
```

The rex command here is extracting a new splunk field named myType from the existing message field based on the supplied regular expression.